# LP how to sum up positive free variables and negative free variables separately?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming

For an LP problem where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are free variables (which may take positive or negative values), I want to bound the sums of $a_i\cdot x_i$ where $x_i>0$, and where $x_i<0$.

I suspect this requires MIP with a sign variable for each $x_i$.

Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Henry, welcome to OR.SE, I think you should use some binary variables to first split the positive and negative variables and then some upon those variables (I assume that $a_i$s are constant-coefficient).

Comment: thanks for your comment.  i think this is the only approach.  the a[i]'s are constant and can be positive or negative.

Answer (score 14):

This can be done using the standard trick of splitting each free variable into the difference of two nonnegative variables:

$$x_{i}=u_{i}-v_{i}$$

where $u \geq 0$ and $v \geq 0$.

If your constraint is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \max(x_{i},0) \leq b$$

with $a \geq 0$, then this can be written as

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} u_{i} \leq b.$$

For the constraint

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \min(x_{i},0) \geq -b$$

with $a \geq 0$, use

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} v_{i} \leq b.$$

Note that it's easy to formulate related constraints that can't be formulated using LP.  For example, a constraint like

$$\sum_{i} a_{i} \max(x_{i},0) \geq b$$

with $a_{i} \geq 0$ is nonconvex and thus can't possibly be represented with LP.  In that case, you might formulate the problem using 0-1 integer variables to encode whether variables are positive or negative.

Comment: Just to be clear, "can't possibly be represented with LP" means "requires binary variables and turns the LP into a MILP".

Comment: thank you for the informative response.  this clarifies the problem and helps me out.